# Output current of op-amp of following circuit

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier

i'm trying solve one question of question paper. [image]

so from figure
I can say that
(1) Iout is Ib and i have equation Ic =BIb. but i have not Ic.
(2) Ib = Vcc-Vbe/Rb. but i have not Rb.

Anyone have another hint??

Comment: Well, you know what op amps do, right? That should tell you what the voltage across that resistor is.

Comment: Remember an opamp's two special properties: Input current is zero and terminal (inverting and non-inverting) voltages are equal. These are your hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have negative feedback and that means the op-amp will drive its output high or low until the two inputs are at the same voltage. This is how negative feedback works. So if you have 2 volts on the +input then, you must have 2 volts at -input.

This means Ie is 2/R3 etc...

Don't forget that Ie = Ic + Ib.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks . but how to find Ic when Rc is not given?

Comment: **Forget** that you can only determine Ic if you know Rc because Rc almost never determines Ic. Andy has helped you find Ie, there is also a Beta which helps to determine ... and then you can detemine Ic.

Comment: sorry. i got it Ie =(1+B)Ib

Comment: Precisely amigo.

Answer (score 0):

If the OpAmp is operating in linear mode:

The gain of OpAmp is one and it is negative feedback since the feedback is being collected from emitter of transistor. The same voltage appears on emitter of Q1 as input voltage.

So Ie = Vin / R

Ic of Q1 is nearly equal to Ie.

then you can find Ib

Ib = Ic / B

This is a voltage controlled current source.